# jQuery $.get freezing on execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following script which performs an 'infinite-scroll' style function:

```
    var next_page_link = $('.wp-pagenavi a:eq(-2)').attr('href'); 

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop()  > $(document).height() / 2) {
            $.get(next_page_link, function(data){
                    if ($(data).find('.wp-pagenavi a:eq(-2)').attr('href') != next_page_link) {
                        next_page_link = $(data).find('.wp-pagenavi a:eq(-2)').attr('href');
                        var content = $(data).find('#multiple_product_top_container').html();
                        $('#multiple_product_top_container').append(content);
                    }
            });                 
        }
    });
```

The one problem I've encountered is that each time the `$.get` function runs, the browser would freeze for 2-3 seconds or more and only un-freeze when the next page has been completely loaded.

My question is, is it possible to set the `$.get` function to run asynchronously or some other method which will eliminate the freezing?

Btw, I know that it's possible to use a server side script but I've encountered a lot of conflicts and it's more complicated involving more parsing.

Thanks

Comment: $.get is asynchronous must be a problem with your callback

Comment: Is your call to `$.get` debounced?  Or can an impatient person trigger it over and over?

Comment: @Paul 'debounced'? I haven't encountered that before. Can you explain a little bit what it does? Thanks

Comment: Sometimes wrapping the code in a `setTimeout(fn, 0);` helps. It's actually used in many js libraries

Comment: @Paul Btw I set the following `if ($(data).find('.wp-pagenavi a:eq(-2)').attr('href') != next_page_link) {` to try and eliminate any duplicate pages being loaded

Comment: The problem is probably with all the AJAX requests that are bombarding the server, as a new request is created for every scroll (check your network tab in Chrome to see what I mean). Add a condition that a new request can't happen until the old one finishes.

Comment: Let's say there's an onscreen button marked "update" and a click handler `clickUpdate()`. Normally each click of the `update` button will invoke `clickUpdate()`.  If that does AJAX back to the server, an impatient user who clicks repeatedly can consume a lot of resources with rapid clicks of the button.  The solution is rate limiting, sometimes called debouncing. The underscoreJS library provides a `_.debounce(func, delay)` wrapper for this purpose.  When  the debounced function is called repeatedly, it will only pass one call to `func` every `delay` ms.

Comment: @eithedog How do I set it so that a new request can't happen until the old one finishes?

Comment: @Paul so basically debouncing is a bit like `setTimeout` ?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a script on your page doing something stupid like `$.ajaxSetup({async: false});`? Essentially making all AJAX calls synchronous, which would lock up the browser while it's waiting for a server response.

Comment: @user2028856 I would bet setTimeout is used to implement _.debounce()

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yea, I'm definitely sure I don't have anything like that at all. This is pretty much all of the code in this snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer to question from comment: `How do I set it so that a new request can't happen until the old one finishes?`

You use a [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29):

```
var semaphore = true;
var next_page_link = $('.wp-pagenavi a:eq(-2)').attr('href'); 

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop()  > $(document).height() / 2 && semaphore) {
        semaphore = false;
        $.get(next_page_link, function(data){
            semaphore = true;
                if ($(data).find('.wp-pagenavi a:eq(-2)').attr('href') != next_page_link) {
                    next_page_link = $(data).find('.wp-pagenavi a:eq(-2)').attr('href');
                    var content = $(data).find('#multiple_product_top_container').html();
                    $('#multiple_product_top_container').append(content);
                }
        });                 
    }
});
```

It would be a good idea to add a condition, that no new requests are to be made when you've already retrieved all that's possible to retrieve.

Comment: This is a really nifty idea, works perfect! Thanks a lot!  :D